# PostgreSQL hash a column using SHA256 and a pre-defined salt

Tags: postgresql, hash, sha

I'm using: PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit  running on AWS as Aurora (RDS).

I have managed to get the below working

```
SELECT encode(digest('email@example.com', 'sha256'),'hex');
```

But I need to use a salt provided by a 3rd party. Let's say for arguments sake the salt is 'this_is_my_salt'. How can I use this? i could only find examples that generate the salt using algorithms.

The vendor wants us to use their hash to compare email addresses in their database with ours. They haven't specified their Database system, but showed me their query which is:

```
SELECT 'email@example.com' as unhashed_email, sha2('shared_salt_value' || lower('email@example.com')) as hashed_email
```

And this produces a different hash to me trying the example in postgres using one of the answers below:

```
SELECT encode(digest('email@example.com' || 'shared_salt_value', 'sha256'),'hex');
```

My hash starts with db17e....
Their hash starts with b6c84....

Could it be encoding or something causing the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is trivial, just concatenate the string with the salt:

```
SELECT encode(digest('this_is_my_salt' || 'email@example.com', 'sha256'),'hex');
```

Comment: Your example works and produces a hash (as do other examples) but for some reason the resulting hash doesn't match the hash from the vendors system (they showed me the query they're using and the resulting hash, but not the database technology they are using). All I know is they specify SHA256 (which I'm doing). I've updated my answer with what information I have.

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to copy someone else's algorithm. Obviously, they use the salt in a different way. Why don't you ask them for the algorithm they are using? With good security, they don't have to keep it a secret.

Comment: I did ask them. They just advised they are using SHA256 with the salt example I've shown above. I didn't say I wanted to 'copy someone else's algorithm' because as far as I understand, if you use SHA256 and the same salt, you should expect the same hash value for the same string (in this case, an email address). However the sample hashed value they show me, is different to what I can produce using your example above - or any other example I can find.

Comment: If I put the email address and salt in my example, into this website https://www.symbionts.de/tools/hash/sha256-hash-salt-generator.html it produces the hashed value the same as the vendor has shown it. Why is PostgreSQL producing a different value to this website as an example?

Comment: That web page says it uses `SHA256(SALT(STRING)+STRING)` - that's the algorithm. So they concatenate them the other way around. I have adapted my answer to that.